# How to show time difference in flutter like facebook

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing an application in which I want to show difference of time like **facebook** does. The following piece of code shows time difference as **yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss**

```
timestamp.toDate().difference(DateTime.now()).toString(),
```

I want it to show time in seconds if its less than a minutes. After 60 seconds it should show difference of time in terms of minutes only and seconds part should be removed. After 60 minutes it should show time in terms of hours and minutes and seconds part should be removed. Finally when its 24 hours it should show time in days ago. 
Your precious advice, suggestions and opinions are most welcome. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a simple  if else condition. Here is an example, you can configure it as you like

```
String getTimeDifferenceFromNow(DateTime dateTime) {
  Duration difference = DateTime.now().difference(dateTime);
  if (difference.inSeconds < 5) {
    return "Just now";
  } else if (difference.inMinutes < 1) {
    return "${difference.inSeconds}s ago";
  } else if (difference.inHours < 1) {
    return "${difference.inMinutes}m ago";
  } else if (difference.inHours < 24) {
    return "${difference.inHours}h ago";
  } else {
    return "${difference.inDays}d ago";
  }
}
```